# PreOrder Traversal Iterativ vs Recursive Time Complexity

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am working with trees for my web application. For example a create a profile site which each profil can have 0..n friends. Also, I want to search a friend in a best time. For that I used Binary Search Tree and Breadh First Search (BFS).

I meausured the time of my both function for searching a friend in my list recursive and iterative and I was surprised that the recursion function was more faster. I thought iterativ functions are faster then iterative and I just used the while loop once in my iterative function which the time complexity is O(n). Can someone explain what is wrong here and why the recursive function is faster:

**Time Recursive: 1.3000000035390258**

```
 preorderRec(root){
    if(root === null) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(root.data);
    if(root.left) {
      this.preorderRec(root.left);
    }
    if(root.right) {
      this.preorderRec(root.right);
    }
    return root;

  }
```

**Time Iterative: 0.997000001117587**

```
   preOrderIterativ(root) {
if(root === null) {
  return;
}
const stack = [root];
const stack2 = [];
while(stack.length) {
  //const node = stack.pop();
  const node = stack.pop();
  stack2.push(node)
  if(node.left) {
    stack.push(node.left)
  }
  if(node.right) {
    stack.push(node.right)
  }
}

return stack2;
```

}
}

**Solution:** The problem was the console.log within the while loop. I used repl.it as editor and after I delete the console.log the performance improved

Comment: Is that the full code? Your preorderRec function walks the tree, but doesn't do anything with it. There's no pushing, popping, or returning like there is in the iterative version, and the iterative version doesn't look like it will look at more than 1 node.

Comment: Logic of your preOrderIterativ function is incorrect, is it the same program whose test results are given above?

Comment: `java` != `javascript`. Come on, it even says so right there in the tooltip of both!!!

Comment: Hi, the recursion function is just return the root

Comment: @NicholasTower The `preorderRec` code logs all node data. `preOrderIterativ` is flawed and only logs the data of the tree root, since it never iterates the children.

Comment: Ok, I could create an second stack and push the nodes in to it. After that I could loop it but then the time complexity will be not better. Have updated my iterative code

Comment: @NoahTony No second stack. You need the left/right push logic *inside* the loop.

Comment: @i dont think you are testing it right as preOrderIterative doesnt iterate anything you just warp root with array and then remove it(i have no idea why) and preorderRec just run on your tree(i guss there is only root) and do nothing. so the test it self is wrong

Comment: I can do it within a while loop or outside from while loop. After deleted the console.log within the while loop the time improvied significantly to 0.99...

Answer (score 0):

On the iterative solution you are using another data structure (`array`). On top of that you are performing insertion `push` and deletion `pop` operations constantly. Each of those operations are `O(n)` time complexity. With the recursive solution you are using `call stack` which is how `javascript` runs things. I don't know Big O for that.

Comment: Ok strange. How can I make it as stack? I thought the add and remove operations are O(1). I didn't understand the different with array and stack not. Whats the different of it if I create an function add instead of using the push functionality?

Comment: You can manually create a Linked List and use it as a stack. That will give you O(1) insertion and removal.